# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Java code for my java class, and I'm getting the following error message when I run the code:

```
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int;"
```

Here is the assignment:

```
"Write a program that reads in a single digit number from the keyboard into an
integer variable. Your program will then print the number spelled out. If the user
types in a number that is more than one digit, your program must print an error
message. If the user types in a negative number, your program should print the word
"negative" before the digit spelled out."
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadsNumber{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] a = new String[10];

         a[0] = "Zero";
         a[1] = "One";
         a[2] = "Two";
         a[3] = "Three";
         a[4] = "Four";
         a[5] = "Five";
         a[6] = "Six";
         a[7] = "Seven";
         a[8] = "Eight";
         a[9] = "Nine";

         Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(System.in);  
         int integer;

         while(true){
             System.out.println("Input an integer: ");
             integer = inputStream.next();
             if (integer < 0)
                 System.out.println("negative");
             else if (integer > 9)
                 System.out.println("error");
             else 
                 System.out.println(a[integer]);
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: What do _you_ think the error means? What does `next()` return? What is `integer` declared as?

Answer (score 2):

The [`next` method returns a `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) and it can't be automatically converted to an `int`.  Call [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) instead.

```
integer = inputStream.nextInt();
```

You may also want to call `hasNextInt()` to determine if what's next on the `Scanner` is actually an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to <strike>parse the integer first</strike> use [`Scanner#nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--):

```
integer = inputStream.nextInt();
```

That will then read a series of characters from the input, and convert them to an integer. If the input is invalid (not an integer, or too large), an exception will be thrown and your program will terminate.

Answer (score 1):

My Dear friend you have used scanner to get the input as an integer but you have used `inputstream.next();`

but as your input is a integer you have to use `inputstream.nextInt();`
because next() is used to get a string and nextInt() to get a Integer.